# How to extract phrase and append it to new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract a particular phrase that has -x, -y, -z letters at the end from a column, and then from that phrase I have to extract these -x, -y, -z letters and append them to a new column.

for Example from the food column

```
      I ate food -s
      I ate food -c
      I ate  food -v
      I ate  food -u
```

I extract -s, -c, -v, -u and append it to new column monitoring

Comment: Could you edit your question to include example data (as text, not images) and runnable code that you've tried so far? [minimal-reproducible-example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added a screen shot, hope this hekps

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.str.extract` with negative lookahead.

```py
df['monitoring'] = df['food'].str.extract('food (-[scvu])(?![\w])')
```

`(?![\w])` means "fail the match if the next character is in \w".

```
print(df)

                                  food monitoring
0                        I ate food -s         -s
1                        I ate food -c         -c
2                       I ate  food -v         -v
3                       I ate  food -u         -u
4   I ate food -s today in the morning         -s
5   I ate food -S today in the morning        NaN
6                               BV-SCP        NaN
7                    diet -restrictive        NaN
8                    diet -sestrictive        NaN
9                 diet -v -restrictive        NaN
10                diet -sestrictive -s        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much it does work but I forget to mention in my column there is more data. It is a part of the sentence I ate food -s today in the morning. So from this sentence, I want to look for ate food -s. , ate food -c, ate food -v, ate  food -u.  The solution you gave me does work but along with -s, etc, it brings e rest of the data in sentences, that I do not want . Thanks

Comment: @Data-scientist Updated the answer, use `\S`  to match a non-whitespace character.

Comment: Is it possible to extract just or exact match for ate food -s, v, u or c, and then we can just append that s,u, v or c to the new column? The new step, you told me it is not working. Thanks

Comment: @Data-scientist `df['food'].str.extract('(\-[scvu])')` is just for this.

Comment: it doesn't help it pulls out all the other phrases like in my column has BV-SCP or diet Restrictive, it's not looking at food -s , it's pulling out -SCP or -restrictive

Comment: No, It's still not working with your edited code

Comment: @Data-scientist Then what's the problem and the error sample data?

Comment: I have attached a screen shot